# How kotlin optimizes checks that number belongs to range?

Tags: kotlin

I'm investigating kotlin using decompilation to java code.

I've found one interesting nuance and can't understand how it is implemented.

Here's the kotlin code:

```
val result = 50 in 1..100
```

I'm using intelij idea decompilation to look for the equivalent of java code and here's what we have:

```
public final class Test14Kt {
   private static final boolean result = true;

   public static final boolean getResult() {
      return result;
   }
}
```

So as i understand it, kotlinc somehow knows that the element is in range and saves true to result variable on the stage of compilation.

It's cool. But how is it achieved?

Answer (score 4):

This is very simple [constant folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding):

> Terms in constant expressions are typically simple literals, such as the integer literal 2, but they may also be variables whose values are known at compile time. Consider the statement:
>
> ```
> i = 320 * 200 * 32;
> ```
>
> Most modern compilers would not actually generate two multiply instructions and a store for this statement. Instead, they identify constructs such as these and substitute the computed values at compile time (in this case, 2,048,000). The resulting code would load the computed value and store it rather than loading and multiplying several values.
>
> Constant folding can even use arithmetic identities. When x is an integer type, the value of 0 * x is zero even if the compiler does not know the value of x.

Here,

```
50 in 1..100 == 
1 <= 50 && 50 <= 100 == 
true && true == 
true
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey. Now it's clear. I just was surprised that such form of folding can be applied to complex types, for example ranges...

Comment: Well, `in <x>..<y>` just converts to two comparisons by definition, the range never even appears. Sure, the compiler _could_ actually create the range and call `contains` method on it, but building this in is both easy and a large win.

Comment: Plus the Kotlin developers had the example of Scala which insisted on _not_ doing that and how it hurt performance.

Comment: So in scala there's no such optimization?

Comment: At least when I last heard, there wasn't.